# Difference between 〜げ　and 〜そう

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between ~げ and ~そう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/what-is-the-difference-between-%e3%81%92-and-%e3%81%9d%e3%81%86)

What is the difference between  〜げ　and 〜そう?

Consider for example:

彼が、何か言いたげに近づいて来た。

彼が、何か言いたそうに近づいて来た。

Or are they synonyms?

Comment: Also, if anyone happens to no by any chance: how do you type "づ" on a Mac keyboard? If I have it on hiragana then I can't seem to find it anywhere. "ず" is easy because it's "z-u"...

Comment: `づ` = 'du' on most IME's.

Comment: Just a note: -ge is 気. It may help you interpret it by thinking of it like 気配 (kehai).

Comment: @MattN.:  Since the た line is typed with 't', just use 'd' for the だ line, even if the romaji is a different letter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are very similar, however there is a slight difference in nuance. げ implies a stronger sense of *uncertainty* compared to そう.

So, in your first example, you are not certain whether he wanted to say something or not, while in the second example, you are *almost* certain that he wants to say something.

Another example:

> 彼が楽しそうに話している //#1
>
> 彼が楽しげに話している //#2

If you saw the person and noticed that they were laughing, smiling, etc. You are most likely to use version #1 and not version #2 because you are confident about your conjecture.

However, although in standard dialect there is the distinction I mentioned above, in some dialects (and in young people's slang) they do no make this distinction and げ is used commonly to mean そう.