# Differences between 楽しがちに、楽し気味に、楽しげに、楽しっぽく

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice

Which one of the words above is most suitable in the following sentence and why?

近所の子供たちが校庭で________遊んでいる。

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is 楽しげに. This げ roughly means "-looking", and it attaches mainly to a relatively small set of adjectives that describe emotion. 楽しげ is [listed as a standalone na-adjective](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%A5%BD%E3%81%97%E3%81%92) in jisho.org. Similar words include 悲しげ, 眠たげ, 嬉しげ and さびしげ. See also: [What is the usage of 〜げ and how does it differ from 〜そう or 〜っぽい?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1386/5010) and [Difference between 〜げ　and 〜そう](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9324/5010)

がち and 気味 are wrong because they only attach to a noun or the masu-stem of a verb.

- 病気がち, 遠慮がち, 曇りがち.
- 風邪気味, 遅れ気味, 押し気味.

-っぽい can attach to many words including i-adjectives:

- with i-adjectives: 青っぽい "blueish", 安っぽい "cheap-looking"
- with nouns: 色っぽい, 理屈っぽい, 子供っぽい
- with verbs: 忘れっぽい, 飽きっぽい

When it attaches to the stem of an i-adjective, it forms another i-adjective with an added nuance of "-ish" or "-looking". It's not used with adjectives of emotion. っぽい used like this is not a productive suffix, and you cannot combine an arbitrary i-adjective with っぽい. We can say 安っぽい and 荒っぽい, but not 高っぽい nor 優しっぽい.

(As an exception, you can use っぽい after the dictionary-form of arbitrary adjectives and verbs, although this sounds fairly colloquial: 合ってるっぽい "looks correct", 高いっぽい "looks expensive", 泣いてるっぽい "seems to be weeping". See: [安いらしい, 安いそうだ, and 高っぽい are incorrect?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58933/5010))

Comment: Thank you for explaining! Do がち and 気味 also mean “-ish”, “-looking”?

Comment: @SabinaMirzezadeh Sort of, but がち is more like "apt to ～", and 気味 is more like "has a sign of ～" or "slightly ～".