# Removal of て in Japanese novels

Tags: て-form, renyōkei

Is て sometimes dropped in Japanese Novella?

I'm asking as I recall being told (in one of my previous question's comment section) that て is sometimes dropped in Japanese novels. And yet, when I went to double check this information by searching the individual comment section of all my previously asked questions, I couldn't find the above claim.

Comment: これですかね？　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/68060/9831　または https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65936/9831

Comment: @Chocolateこれですじゃない。

Comment: ^ 「それじゃないです。」ですね。＾＾

Comment: This is answered in your previous question: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65953/5010 It's more accurate to say "連用形 can be followed by て" rather than "dropping て from the te-form".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"Dropped" is not such an accurate word here as the 「て」 is optional in the first place.

The te-form seems to enjoy a rockstar treatment in the world of Japanese-as-a-foreign-language.  Learners love to talk about it, but what many rarely mention (or know about) is its informality.  This is one of the things that took me by surprise when I started mingling with Japanese-learners back in college.

The 連用形{れんようけい} ("continuative form") of a verb or adjective already contains within the meaning of the 「て」 without using the 「て」.

The point I am trying to make is that **the te-form is more informal than the 連用形**.  The te-form is heavily used in our informal, day-to-day conversations because it fits there.  The general tendency, however, is that **the more formal the speech, the less often the te-form is used**.  In novels, therefore, the te-form is used far more often in the quotes than in the prose.

A couple of examples:

> 「あき子はカーテンを**開{あ}け**、『夜の東京タワー、きれいね。』とつぶやいた。」  vs.
>
> 「あき子はカーテンを**開けて**、『夜の東京タワー、きれいね。』とつぶやいた。」

「つぶやく」 = "to murmur".  The chances are that you will encounter the first sentence in a novel.

> 「とも子の瞳{ひとみ}は**大きく、黒く**、どこを見ているのか分{わ}からなかった。」 vs.
>
> 「とも子の瞳は**大きくて、黒くて**、どこを見ているのか分からなかった。」

The second sentence sounds like what you would hear in a casual chat.  You would not find it in a novel, at least not in the prose part.