# Difference between conjunctive forms: ～ます stem and ～て form

Tags: grammar

What's the difference between:

> 朝起きたら、まず顔を**洗い**、コーヒーを**飲み**、新聞を読みます。(ます－form）

and

> 朝起きたら、まず顔を**洗って**、コーヒーを**飲んで**、新聞を読みます。(て－form)

Both have the same meaning, but can I use this conjunctive ます stem with a person which I don't know or with a boss?

Maybe only for the talking or the writing?

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/removal-of-%e3%81%a6-in-japanese-novels/70324#70324

Comment: Thank you for the anwser l'électeur. And thank you for the correction Eiríkr Útlendi ( I didn't know the english term).