# Combining verb and noun for ありがとう

Tags: grammar

There are two sentences I'm looking to combine together:

> 説明ありがとうございます。
>
> 教えていただいてありがとうございます。

The first follows the [noun] + ありがとう pattern, while the second follows the [te-form] + [いただいて] + ありがとう pattern. Would joining them together with と work, as in this?

> 説明と教えていただいてありがとうございます。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 「説明{せつめい}**と**教{おし}えていただいてありがとうございます。」

is not a valid sentence for at least two reasons.

**Reason #1**:

It is ungrammatical for connecting, by using a 「と」,
 a ***noun*** （ご説明） and a ***verb*** phrase （教えていただく）.
This is just not possible.

**Reason #2**:

There is too much overlap in meaning between 「説明」 ("explanation") and 「教える」 ("teaching") that the sentence sounds awkward even if we ignore the fairly big grammar mistake mentioned above.  I feel like saying that if you did one of the two, you would automatically be doing the other.

(Besides the two reasons above, 「と」 is considerably more informal than many J-learners appear to think.  In fact, it is rarely used in formal speech for connecting nouns.  We have 「かつ」, 「および」, etc. for that purpose, but again, those cannot be used to connect a noun to a verb.)

In conclusion, I would suggest that you drop one of the two items that you connected with a 「と」 to form grammatical and natural-sounding sentences such as:

・「丁寧{ていねい}にご説明いただきありがとうございました。」

・「ご教示{きょうじ}いただきありがとうございました。」

・「ご指導{しどう}いただき感謝申{かんしゃもう}し上{あ}げます。」

I changed the 「いただいて」 to 「いただき」 because the te-form is also more informal than many users seem to think.  You might want to read [this Q&A](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/removal-of-%e3%81%a6-in-japanese-novels/70324#70324) regarding this matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But supposing that reason #2 didn't apply and that there were two independent nouns/verbs, is there a good way in giving thanks for both things simultaneously, or is it just better to choose one and drop the other?