# What's going on when a -ku godan verb like "叩く" gets conjugated to "叩かれ"?

Tags: conjugations

Like what's the exact conjugation breakdown going on there? I've spent days scouring various things and I can't for the life of me figure out the exact breakdown causing a "かれ".

I'm not leaving off any conjugation bits, so it's definitely not me misreading something like 叩かれた.

If you could explain what's going on in general terms rather than specifically -ku verbs, that might be more helpful, but I'm at my wits' end and will honestly take anything at this point.

> 力いっぱい背中を叩かれ、大介は思わずよろめいた。

Two friends, the person strongly hitting 大介 on the back is a friend trying to cheer him up. He did it without warning, but it's not aggressive. The sentence is narrative and describing the situation, non-spoken.

Comment: Please include the full sentence and some context, otherwise any answer will have to be a short in the dark...

Comment: @Earthliŋ Edited in for you!

Comment: This is probably answered by this question https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/70321/1628. Please take a look.

Comment: @Earthliŋ So my first instinct was actually right! I'll definitely remember て/た can be dropped (especially in prose, apparently!) from now on! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The conjugation is the passive voice of the verb 叩く, which becomes 叩かれる in the passive. Usually, it would connect to another clause in the て form (叩かれて), but the continuative form (連用形), which is 叩かれ, is also used as a way to connect clauses, especially in written Japanese.