# Which translation is closer to the original Japanese?

Tags: translation, parsing

I'm curious as to whether or not I did a good job with my own stay-as-close-to-the-Japanese-as-possible translation of the following two lines, seeing as how google translate only gave me either partially correct gibberish, or a answer which is surprisingly close to my own translation, but I'm doubtful as it has given me outright not-even-close translations for other sentences in the past.

> 「ここにじっとしていてもしょうがない………か」
>
> 自分を奮い立たせるために、わざと自分の考えを声に出し行動を始めた。
>
> “As far as patiently remaining here it can’t be helped…… I guess.”
>
> I force myself to cheer up as a result, on purpose I vocalize my thought and start the action.
>
> (The above doesn't quite sound right in English, whereas "I force myself to cheer up as a result, on purpose I start the action and vocalize my thought." sounds more natural to a English speaker)

For the top sentence, google translate gave me ""It's no use staying here..." That's what I'm going",
and for the bottom, it gave me "In order to inspire himself, he deliberately began to speak out his thoughts and act."

For the second sentence, which translation is closer to the original Japanese?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ここにじっとしていても
> Even if I stay still here,
>
> しょうがない
> it's meaningless,
>
> ………か。
> ...I guess.
>
> 自分を奮い立たせるために、
> To encourage myself,
>
> わざと自分の考えを声に出し
> I deliberately voiced my thoughts, and
>
> 行動を始めた。
> started a (new) action.

Your parsing and translation indicate that you are still somehow thinking 考えを声に出す and 行動を始めた are "linked", but they are not. 自分の考え is the object of (声に)出す, and 行動 is the object of 始める. Here 出す and 始める are independent two actions with two different objects. It's not "started to voice something" but "voiced something, and then started something". Read this as if they were two different sentences.

> 自分を奮い立たせるために、わざと自分の考えを声に出した。
> To encourage myself, I deliberately voiced my thoughts.
>
> そして行動を始めた。
> Then, I started a (new) action.

The final part of this sentence is structurally no different from a sentence like this:

> パンを食べワインを飲んだ。
> = パンを食べてワインを飲んだ。
> = I ate bread and drank wine.

Note that 食べ and 出し are both 連用形. [One of the most voted question you made is exactly about this.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/70321/removal-of-%E3%81%A6-in-japanese-novels) パン is the object of 食べる, and ワイン is the object of 飲む. Just two independent actions, no relative clauses. It shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Realized I had copied and pasted the older, wrong translation for the second sentence after waking up this morning by accident. Should be fixed, hopefully.

Comment: I guess what threw me off the parsing is that there isn't a comma or a visible te in the 考えを声に出し行動を始めた part of the sentence in the original Japanese, as far as I can tell, whereas you were able to separate the two independent actions immediately into two separate clauses.